# Inner product of fields extension on a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $M$ and $\overline{M}$ be Riemannian manifolds and $f : M \rightarrow \overline{M}$ an isometric immersion. Now, consider $X, Y, Z \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ fields defined on $M$ and let $\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y}, \tilde{Z} \in \mathfrak{X}(\overline{M})$ their extensions to $\overline{M}$, defined by $$ \tilde{X} = (df) (X \circ f^{-1}).$$ I'd like to show that $$\langle \overline{\nabla}_\tilde{Y} \tilde{X},\tilde{Z} \rangle = \langle \nabla_Y X, Z \rangle,$$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denote the Riemannian metric and $\overline{\nabla}$ and $\nabla$ denote the affine connection associated to the metric on $\overline{M}$ and $M$ respectively.

I think it's a standard calculation, but I'm a bit confused with the extensions. I could write $$\langle \overline{\nabla}_\tilde{Y} \tilde{X},\tilde{Z} \rangle = \langle \nabla_Y X, \tilde{Z}^t\rangle + \langle \sigma(Y,X), \tilde{Z}^n,\rangle $$ where $\tilde{Z}^t$ denote the tangent component of $\tilde{Z}$ and $\tilde{Z}^n$ the normal component. Now, we have $$ \langle \overline{\nabla}_\tilde{Y} \tilde{X},\tilde{Z} \rangle = \langle \nabla_Y X, Z\rangle + \langle \sigma(Y,X), \tilde{Z}^n\rangle$$ and the second member must vanish, but I don't know how to prove it.

Anyone can help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can't "define" the extensions of $X,Y,Z$ that way. Your formula $(df)(X\circ f^{-1})$ doesn't make sense to define a vector field on $\overline M$, because $f^{-1}$ is only defined at points of $f(M)$, not on all of $\overline M$. (And, in fact, if $f$ is not injective, it's not even well defined on $f(M)$.)

Comment: What you need to do is let $\tilde X, \tilde Y, \tilde Z$ be _arbitrary_ smooth extensions of $X,Y,Z$ in a neighborhood of a point (where $f$ is injective), and then note that $\tilde Z^n=0$ at points of $M$ because it's equal to $Z$ there.